# How do I connect my app to bluetooth when multiple coding languages are involved?

Tags: c++, xcode, bluetooth

Our team wants to create a game. We think c++ should be the language (so we can use Unreal Engine to develop), but we want the game to be multi-platform (game consoles, iPhone, etc.). The game will require bluetooth connections with an external device. What communicates with bluetooth? The c++, or Swift/Java (or whatever is running on the platform)?

Comment: _"What communicates with bluetooth?"_ Appropriate device drivers?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use the native language for each platform. In other words, use C++ as you originally planned, swift for iOS, Java/Kotlin for Android, etc. It might theoretically take you longer to develop, but these native languages will end up being more versatile/powerful, and you will find a lot of resources that help you in your development. That being said, if you wanted a common language with Bluetooth functionality across multiple platforms, then Xamarin is the closest thing to being that. Not sure how much you can use it to develop a game, but it will give you some level of interoperability. Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [What is Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin#:%7E:text=Xamarin%20is%20built%20on%20top%20of.NET%2C%20which%20automatically,information%20about%20platform-specific%20architecture%2C%20see%20Xamarin.Android%20and%20Xamarin.iOS.)
- [Use C/C++ Libraries with Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/)
- [Xamarin vs Native App Development: Pros and Cons](https://jelvix.com/blog/xamarin-vs-native-app-development)
- [Bluetooth LE for Xamarin](https://servocode.com/blog/servocode.com/blog/bluetooth-le-for-xamarin.forms-how-to-control-things-from-the-level-of-mobile-app)